# Unable to set property...of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I inherited a SharePoint site that deploys several apps. Everything had been working fine for a year and out of no where all the apps stopped loading and I used developer tools in IE11 and got the following: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'relatedNavigationProperty' of undefined or null reference". This is the first time I've used angular so I'm not great with it. The file I'm looking at doesn't even have a 'relatedNavigationProperty' property. I've been scouring the web for hours trying to figure this out to no avail. Any suggestions for what I should be looking for would be greatly appreciated.

Looked through all related scripts for relatedNavigationProperty
Checked Emulation information- Document mode = 11
Verified that this is an issue for all users

```
 function createInternalInjector(cache, factory) {

    function getService(serviceName) {
      if (cache.hasOwnProperty(serviceName)) {
        if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
          throw $injectorMinErr('cdep', 'Circular dependency found: {0}',
                    serviceName + ' <- ' + path.join(' <- '));
        }
        return cache[serviceName];
      } else {
        try {
          path.unshift(serviceName);
          cache[serviceName] = INSTANTIATING;
          return cache[serviceName] = factory(serviceName);
        } catch (err) {
          if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
            delete cache[serviceName];
          }
          throw err;
        } finally {
          path.shift();
        }
      }
    }
```

I expect apps to be loading and working as they previously were but the landing page loads and will not continue on to the apps

Developer tools throws the error at the 'throw err' line...obviously

Comment: Phantom 1.x doesn't have Function.prototype.bind. Just use Phantom 2.x or a polyfill. [_1_](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13794#issuecomment-172672311).

Answer (score 0):

This error `Unable to set property`relatedNavigationProperty`of undefined or null reference` implies that the property called `relatedNavigationProperty` is being set on a variable that has a value of undefined or null.

For example:

```
undefined.myProp = true;
null.myProp = true;
```

You need to log out the values of `cache`, `factory`, and any other variables in that code to see what's happening. `relatedNavigationProperty` is probably being passed in.

Comment: I haven't been able to verify if this will solve the problem because I'm not able to access certain parts of the site but I'll up vote you instead of marking it correct.